# Apache POI отключить конвертирование строки в дату

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Создаю xls файл через Apache POI, при заполнение вношу значение вида `02.01.5`, при чтение получаю `02-янв-2005`.

Тип ячейки выставляю в строку и при создание файла и при чтении.

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
```

Как отключить автоматическое преобразование или получить исходное значение.

Answer (score 1):

Решение :

```
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@"));
```

и при создание ячейки

```
sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(cell.getColumnIndex(),style);
```